# Randomly loosing internet connection with Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: 14.04, internet

I've just made fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm experimenting strange behaviour of the internet connection: sometimes I cannot send receive any data, even if the connection is still active as indicated by the applet showing the status of the network manager.

Every time I have have to go with the mouse and click (turn-off) "Wireless". Then I wait for a couple of seconds and turn it on again.

I mounted an usb wifi-stick listed as 100% compatible with Ubuntu 14.04 (i.e. the **TP-LINK TL-WN821N USB Adapter WLAN 802.11n 300Mbit Stick**). During the installation the stick was recognized with zero problems, but now I cannot understand how to deal with this frustrating issue.

I searched across Ubuntu forums but I've read just about generic indications. No clear assertions about the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, because these operations involve editing your system configuration at the kernel level, before you do any of this, BACK UP ANY IMPORTANT FILES, AND MAKE SURE YOU HAVE A BOOTABLE UBUNTU LIVE USB / DVD / CD. I cannot stress this enough. If for some reason your system crashes completely during these operations (though it shouldn't), you may want to have backups of anything important and a way to reinstall your OS if the need arises.

Visit this page, and select your hardware version number from the drop down list. (you should be able to find this number on the USB stick):

http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WN821N_V4.html#Driver

There are many drivers provided here in .zip files. The Linux driver file for V4 also contains a .pdf installation guide. If your version is V4, download the driver for Linux kernel, open, and follow the instructions in the .pdf file. If you have V4, stop reading here. The above should fix your problem.

If your version is V3, you need to download a special tool along with any dependencies, by opening up a terminal and entering the following code:

```
sudo apt-get install ndisgtk
```

Enter your password, press Y then Enter when prompted.

Then, go to the V3 driver download page, and download the driver for Windows Vista / XP.

Next, in the terminal, type

```
sudo ndisgtk
```

In the graphical interface, you should be able to load the appropriate driver from the 'Windows XP' folder in the downloaded file (the file name is 'arusb_XP.inf')

After you have it loaded, run

```
sudo nautilus
```

Now, go to root/etc/modprobe.d

Create a new .conf file here by right clicking and selecting New > Empty File (you can name it whatever you want, as long as it ends in .conf). Right click the file, and open with gedit. Type the following code in the text editor.

`blacklist ar9170usb`

Save, and close the file.

Now, create another .conf file in the same place. Open in gedit, enter

```
blacklist carl9170usb
```

Save and close.

Now, in the terminal, type the following and press enter:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

At the bottom of the text file, add the following line:

```
ndiswrapper
```

Save, close, then restart your system. Everything should be working.

If your version number is V5 or earlier than V3, the website does not seem to offer any drivers, but it is often the case that the drivers for a different version may work in the event that no drivers are offered. Trial and error may be necessary in this case to figure out which, if any, of the drivers available on the website actually work for these versions.

Alternatively, you may be able to obtain professional assistance by contacting TP-Link Tech Support using one of the methods listed on this page:

http://www.tp-link.com/en/contact.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just now I've discovered that I have the version 4.2 that is not equipped with the Atheros chip but with the Realtek one:

_Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter_

So I bought the wrong version :( :(
The usb stick has a label reporting 4.2 as version. More than this, the available driver on the TP-link website is suggested for kernel versions max 3.10.10 while my kernel version is  "3.19.0-51-generic". What I should do?

Comment: Another thing.
I have gone on the ubuntu web page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsTP-Link listing supported TP-Link adapters. There (scroll down the page) I found a way to make the realtek working. What you think about the proposed solutions?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**
I've religiously followed the instructions published by pvret on github and I've got the RTL8192CU realtek driver modified to work with Ubuntu 14.04:
http://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes

I've tested the connection for more than 8 hours, no one time the wifi connection was lost. So the problem is definitely solved.

**Note:** after restarting Ubuntu I've gone in panic 'cause the network manager (in the bottom-right corner of the screen) prompted me with the allarming message "No connection available". The same happened after turning off and on again the PC.
To solve this, I've just unplugged the usb-stick and plugged it again in the same usb port after few seconds. Et voilà, the connection was available again.

Hope this helps.